# python Traceback Keyerror using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-import, python-3.5

I have an error in my python code:

```
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import traceback

from time import localtime, strftime

def display(result):      

        print ('Weather in Suwon, Asia at ' + strftime('%H:%M', localtime()) + '\n')
        print ('Condition: ' + result['cond'])
        print ('Temparature: ' + result['temp'] + u"\N{DEGREE SIGN}" + 'C')
        print ('RealFeel: ' + result['realfeel'] + u"\N{DEGREE SIGN}" + 'C')
        print (result['humid'])
        print (result['cloud'])
        print

def main():
    with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.accuweather.com/en/kr/suwon/223670/current-weather/223670") as url:
        html = url.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

    soup = soup.find('div', {'id':'detail-now'})

    result = {}

    while soup:
        if soup.get('class') == 'cond':
            result['cond'] = soup.text
        elif soup.get('class') == 'temp':
            result['temp'] = soup.text.replace("°", "")
        elif soup.get('class') == 'realfeel':
            s = soup.text.replace("°", "")
            result['realfeel'] = s.replace("RealFeel® ", "")
        elif soup.get('cellspacing') == None and soup.get('class') == 'stats':
            ss = soup.findAll('li')
            for li in ss:
                if 'humid' in li.text:
                    result['humid'] = li.text.replace(":", ": ")
                elif 'Cloud' in li.text:
                    result['cloud'] = li.text.replace(":", ": ")
            break

        soup = soup.findNext()

    display(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

---

The error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/untitled0.py", line 60, in 
>       main()
>
> File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/untitled0.py", line 55, in main
>       display(result)
>
> File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/untitled0.py", line 20, in display
>       print ('Condition: ' + result['cond'])
>
> KeyError: 'cond'

Why is this error appearing?

---

My python version is 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

None of your conditions evaluate to True so you never create the cond key in your dict, you are also going the wrong way about parsing, use the classes to get the data you want:

```
def display(result):
    print('Weather in Suwon, Asia at ' + strftime('%H:%M', localtime()) + '\n')
    print('Condition: ' + result['cond'])
    print('Temparature: ' + result['temp'])
    print('RealFeel: ' + result["realfeel"])
    print(result['humid'])
    print(result['cloud'])



def main():
    with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.accuweather.com/en/kr/suwon/223670/current-weather/223670") as url:
        html = url.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    soup = soup.find('div', {'id': 'detail-now'})
    result = {"realfeel": soup.select_one("span.realfeel").text.split(None, 1)[1],
              "temp": soup.select_one("span.temp").text.strip(),
              "cond": soup.select_one("span.cond").text.strip(),
              "humid": soup.select_one("ul.stats li").text,
              "cloud": soup.select_one("ul.stats li:nth-of-type(4)").text}


    display(result)
```

If we run the code we get:

```
In [2]: main()
Humidity: 68%
22°
Weather in Suwon, Asia at 11:17

Condition: Mostly cloudy
Temparature: 22°
RealFeel: 22°
Humidity: 68%
Cloud Cover: 95%
```

Comment: THANKS so much!! :) you are my hero!! haha